# Чтение данных из бинарного файла в очередь

Tags: c, файлы, вывод, очередь, динамические-структуры

После записи очереди в бинарный файл не получается эту же очередь прочитать из файла

```
    case 10:
            if((f_open = fopen("write.dat","wb")) == NULL )
          {
             puts("Файл на запись не был открыт!\n");
             return 0;
          }
           p =list; //list - указатель на 1 элемент в очереди 
                    // p - указатель который перемещается по очереди
           while(p !=NULL)
           {
              fwrite(p,sizeof(LEL),1,f_open);
              p=p->next;

           }

           fclose(f_open);
           printf("Данные в файл были успешно записаны!\n\n"); break;
    case 11:
             if((f_read = fopen("write.dat","rb")) == NULL )
          {
             puts("Файл на запись не был открыт!\n");
             return 0;
          }
          counter = 0;
            LEL obj; // объект типа LEL
          while(p != NULL)
          {   p = &obj;
              fread(p,sizeof(LEL),1,f_read);
              if(counter == 0) list = p; // list указатель на начало очереди
              ++counter;
              p = p->next;
          }

           fclose(f_read); break;
```

При выводе очередь оказывается пустой, мб быть кто-то сталкивался

```
typedef struct inform
{
    char fname[12]; //имя
    char sname[12]; //фамилия
    char tname[12]; // отчество
    char pnumber[16];//номер телефона
    char address[31]; //адресс
    char family[11]; //семейное положение
    int sallary; //запрплата
} INFORM;

typedef struct list_elem
{
  INFORM inform;
  struct list_elem *next;
}LEL;
```

Comment: @Harry Вот мой LEL

Answer (score 2):

У вас вообще странное чтение...

```
LEL obj; // объект типа LEL
```

Оп! чему тут равен `p`? *Куда* он указывает?

```
while(p != NULL)
{   
    p = &obj;
```

Ага, он **всегда** указывает на `obj`, т.е. вы все читаете в одно и то же место...

```
    fread(p,sizeof(LEL),1,f_read);
    if(counter == 0) list = p; // list указатель на начало очереди
    ++counter;
```

А вот тут интересно - вы считываете из файла указатель `next`. С чего вы решили, что под него уже выделена память, да вообще, что он указывает хоть куда-то в разумное место? Ваша ошибка с `p = &obj` позволила программе не свалиться с ошибкой доступа к памяти, а вот если бы вы попытались разыменовывать ваш `p` - вот тут бы вы получили неприятности...

```
    p = p->next;
}
```

Словом, вам при записи нужно писать только часть `inform` - благо, это plain old data, и ее можно читать/писать через `fread/fwrite`. Но писать в файл адрес `next` - просто глупо: при чтении он будет указывать куда? где что-то было при прошлом запуске программы?

Вам надо выделять память для узла, читать `inform`, и настраивать указатели - по сути, строить весь список заново, как вы его, вероятно, где-то строили вручную - только не с клавиатуры, а из файла...